# Trouble uninstalling CUDA 9.1 and installing 9.0

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvcc, cudnn, ubuntu-18.04

Config - Intel Core i5-7200U, Intel HD Graphics, NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
OS - Ubuntu 18.04

On a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04, I was following this guide https://hackernoon.com/up-and-running-with-ubuntu-nvidia-cuda-cudnn-tensorflow-and-pytorch-a54ec2ec907d to set up CUDA, cuDNN, TensorFlow and PyTorch with GPU support. After installing CUDA according to the guide, `nvcc --version` found no installation and asked me to use this command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

This installed CUDA 9.1 according to nvcc --version. I tried uninstalling it using this command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda*
```

Now cuda directory doesn't exist in usr/local but nvcc --version still shows cuda 9.1 installed.
I need to uninstall any last traces of 9.1 and install 9.0 to continue installation of cuDNN. [image: Following is the screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can leave cuda 9.1 alone. Just modify your path configuration to use cuda 9.0.
Change `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin` to `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin`